# Building a background gradient with tiles

Tags: html, css, background, gradient

I'm trying to acheive the following background in html/css:
[image]

I searched for ways to make gradients already but i only found smooth gradients, couldn't find *tiles-based* gradients. I decided to try making this gradient with flexboxes (see the following snippet:

```css
div.s-t-numbers-background {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
div.s-t-numbers-background-column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
div.s-t-numbers-background-tile {
  background-color: #FFFAAA;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="s-t-numbers-background">
  <div class='s-t-numbers-background-column'>
    <div class='s-t-numbers-background-tile'>tile</div>
    <div class='s-t-numbers-background-tile'>tile</div>
    <div class='s-t-numbers-background-tile'>tile</div>
    <div class='s-t-numbers-background-tile'>tile</div>
  </div>
  <div class='s-t-numbers-background-column'>
    <div class='s-t-numbers-background-tile'>tile</div>
    <div class='s-t-numbers-background-tile'>tile</div>
    <div class='s-t-numbers-background-tile'>tile</div>
    <div class='s-t-numbers-background-tile'>tile</div>
  </div>
  <div class='s-t-numbers-background-column'>
    <div class='s-t-numbers-background-tile'>tile</div>
    <div class='s-t-numbers-background-tile'>tile</div>
    <div class='s-t-numbers-background-tile'>tile</div>
    <div class='s-t-numbers-background-tile'>tile</div>
  </div>
  <div class='s-t-numbers-background-column'>
    <div class='s-t-numbers-background-tile'>tile</div>
    <div class='s-t-numbers-background-tile'>tile</div>
    <div class='s-t-numbers-background-tile'>tile</div>
    <div class='s-t-numbers-background-tile'>tile</div>
  </div>
  <div class='s-t-numbers-background-column'>
    <div class='s-t-numbers-background-tile'>tile</div>
    <div class='s-t-numbers-background-tile'>tile</div>
    <div class='s-t-numbers-background-tile'>tile</div>
    <div class='s-t-numbers-background-tile'>tile</div>
  </div>
  <div class='s-t-numbers-background-column'>
    <div class='s-t-numbers-background-tile'>tile</div>
    <div class='s-t-numbers-background-tile'>tile</div>
    <div class='s-t-numbers-background-tile'>tile</div>
    <div class='s-t-numbers-background-tile'>tile</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The upper-left color is: `#8e003f` and the lower-right color is: `#f02435`
Iwould be happy to avoid doing this with divs and use CSS if anyone has a trick to do this.

Comment: Why not just create it as an image background? background-size:cover;

Comment: Would be easier I know, but I have to make my page very light and also responsive, the image background would be my last resort. (I am also required by my client to be able to edit the colors :D )

Comment: Is there any pattern that your gradient can follow? You need JS for this I think. Then you can specify number of boxes, colors and any other properties that you might need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

customize your colors and positions on your own. Im afraid that this dont have large support acros browsers. Mentioned background image would be much better
(you can have 6x4px png, size of such file is not big)

```css
div{
  width:160px;
  height: 240px;
  border:1px solid;
background: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='4' height='6'><rect fill='#8e003f' x='0' y='0' width='1' height='1'/><rect fill='#8e003e' x='0' y='1' width='1' height='1'/><rect fill='#8e003d' x='0' y='2' width='1' height='1'/><rect fill='#8e003c' x='0' y='3' width='1' height='1'/><rect fill='#8e003b' x='0' y='4' width='1' height='1'/><rect fill='#8e003a' x='0' y='5' width='1' height='1'/><rect fill='#8e003f' x='1' y='0' width='1' height='1'/><rect fill='#9e003d' x='1' y='1' width='1' height='1'/><rect fill='#Ae003b' x='1' y='2' width='1' height='1'/><rect fill='#Ce0038' x='1' y='3' width='1' height='1'/><rect fill='#f02437' x='1' y='4' width='1' height='1'/><rect fill='#f02435' x='1' y='5' width='1' height='1'/><rect fill='#8e003f' x='2' y='0' width='1' height='1'/><rect fill='#Ae003d' x='2' y='1' width='1' height='1'/><rect fill='#C0243b' x='2' y='2' width='1' height='1'/><rect fill='#D02439' x='2' y='3' width='1' height='1'/><rect fill='#E02437' x='2' y='4' width='1' height='1'/><rect fill='#f02435' x='2' y='5' width='1' height='1'/><rect fill='#a0243a' x='3' y='0' width='1' height='1'/><rect fill='#b02439' x='3' y='1' width='1' height='1'/><rect fill='#c02438' x='3' y='2' width='1' height='1'/><rect fill='#d02437' x='3' y='3' width='1' height='1'/><rect fill='#e02436' x='3' y='4' width='1' height='1'/><rect fill='#f02435' x='3' y='5' width='1' height='1'/></svg>");
  background-size: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use gradients to do your design in a row (or a column).
Then, just repeat the gradient in the other rows, offsetting it a step:

```css
.test {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  background-image: 
    linear-gradient(to right,yellow 25%, green 25%, green 50%, blue 50%, blue 75%, red 75%),       linear-gradient(to right,yellow 25%, green 25%, green 50%, blue 50%, blue 75%, red 75%),       linear-gradient(to right,yellow 25%, green 25%, green 50%, blue 50%, blue 75%, red 75%),       linear-gradient(to right,yellow 25%, green 25%, green 50%, blue 50%, blue 75%, red 75%);
  background-size: 200% 25%;
  background-position: 0% 0%, 25% 25%, 50% 50%, 75% 75%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

ok thinking about it, looks like a table would do the trick, much less html and css code for that. Then style the background colour per table cell

```
<table id="red">
  <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td>number</td>
     <td>number</td>
     <td>number</td>
     <td>number</td>
     <td>number</td>
     <td>number</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>number</td>
     <td>number</td>
     <td>number</td>
     <td>number</td>
     <td>number</td>
     <td>number</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>number</td>
     <td>number</td>
     <td>number</td>
     <td>number</td>
     <td>number</td>
     <td>number</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>number</td>
     <td>number</td>
     <td>number</td>
     <td>number</td>
     <td>number</td>
     <td>number</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

.red 
{
  border-collapse:collapse;
}

.red tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1)
{
  background:dark red;
}

.red tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(2)
{
  background:less dark red;
}

and so on

If you're using sass you can predefine you colours as constants which would be great.